# Accounts Payable Account not returned in QBO Account Query

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

In QBO, `Select * From Account` is not returning the `Accounts Payable` account in the result set. I am doing this in a Sandbox via API Explorer (and via C# SDK). Anyone know if this is by design or a bug?

Comment: Does QuickBooks actually have an Accounts Payable account in it? What does the XML/JSON response from Intuit look like? What does your HTTP request look like? No one can help you troubleshoot without any of this vital information.

Comment: I did the select statement exactly as I stated in the question in Intuits API Explorer.  So the request and response are irrelevant in this case.

Yes, there is an AP account setup in QBO. You can see it when looking at a vendor Bill I'm the UI.

Comment: Works fine for me in API Explorer. I think you expect to be able to get anywhere on this, you need to post more information. The XML/JSON responses are NOT irrelevant -- those are what allow you to actually track down errors and, if it's a legitimate bug, report it to Intuit.

Comment: I would also post a screenshot of the GUI list of the Chart of Accounts, which will help determine if it's a true bug so we can submit to Intuit to have them fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was an issue based upon an incorrect expectation on my end. I was testing the same functionality in integrating our app with both QBD and QBO. I had seen the AP account in the UI, but it was in QBD not QBO. I thought that the Accounts Payable account was a default account automatically created in QBO, but that was incorrect and the account was not in fact there in the QBO UI. Though it is a system created account, it is not created until you create your first vendor bill, at which time QBO then automatically creates this account.

So if you have a new QBO sandbox company, you will not see the AP account until you create your first vendor bill.